# Python - remove non-unique elements between lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists of image ids that belong to a class of images such as dog and cat. Some of the images contain both dogs and cats in the image, and I want to remove those images.

Lets say I have

```
{'cat':[1,2,3], 'dog':[2,3,4]}
```

we can see that the images with id 2 and 3 have both cats and dogs. I want to exclude these images to get the following:

```
[[1],[4]]
```

I have tried this so far:

```
from collections import Counter
img_ids = {'cat':[1,2,3], 'dog':[2,3,4]}
flattened = [item for sublist in img_ids.values() for item in sublist]
flattened_unique = [k for k, v in dict(Counter(flattened)).items() if v < 2]
filtered_ids_dfs = []
for key, val in img_ids.items():
  filtered = [x for x in val if x in flattened_unique]
  filtered_ids_dfs.append(filtered)
print(filtered_ids_dfs)
```

Is there a better or more elegant solution to this? Also there may be an arbitrary number of classes, so our dictionary may have cat, dog, chicken etc.

Comment: If there were three such lists `[1, 2, 3]`, `[1, 2, 4, 5]`, `[1, 4, 6, 7]` would the desired output be `[3], [5], [6, 7]` (removing all items in more than one of the inputs) or `[2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [4, 6, 7]` (removing those items that are in all of the inputs)

Comment: python set() would be better choice and will be faster.

Comment: @Kevin could you provide an example with more than just 2 classes? Also it looks like the keys to your dict are irrelevant here.

Comment: @pault The code should work if you do: {'cat':[1, 2, 3], 'dog':[2, 3, 4], 'chicken': [2, 4, 5, 6]}. it should give: [[1],[],[5,6]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = {'cat':[1,2,3], 'dog':[2,3,4]}
n = [[c for c in b if not any(c in h for j, h in d.items() if j != a)] for a, b in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[[1], [4]]
```

Comment: AJax1234, nice solution.

Comment: If we wanted the keys we would do this:
`n = {a:[c for c in b if not any(c in h for j, h in d.items() if j != a)] for a, b in d.items()}`

Comment: @Kevin - this is quadratic time, the solution by @Alexander is more efficient at `O(n)`.

Comment: @pault Isn't Alexander's solution `O(n^2)`, as he iterates over the `items` for every   key-value pair in `d`? (`{k: [item for item in items if item in unique_images] for k, items in d.iteritems()}`)

Comment: The `n` here refers to the iteration through `d`, which his solution only does once. It may be clearer if it was rewritten as `{k: list(set(item)&unique_images) for k, items in d.iteritems()}`. Nevertheless, the best way to measure is by timing it.

Answer (score 5):

First, count how many objects (e.g. cat, dog) there are per image.  Then find the images with only one object (unique images).  Finally, use a dictionary comprehension to find images that are in the unique image list.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'cat':[1,2,3], 'dog':[2,3,4], 'chicken': [2, 4, 5, 6]}

c = Counter([item for items in d.values() for item in items])
unique_images = set(k for k, count in c.iteritems() if count == 1)  # .items() in Python3

>>> {k: [item for item in items if item in unique_images] for k, items in d.iteritems()}  # .items() in Python3
{'cat': [1], 'chicken': [5, 6], 'dog': []}
```

Comment: Alexander, great example with set() , i love using set(), set is faster.

Comment: `[[x] for x ...` doesn't strike me as correct if some of the inputs have many unique items.  If the two lists were `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`, I would expect the output to be `[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]` not `[1], [2], [3], ...`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh You are correct.  I've completely changed my answer.

Comment: FWIW, you can use set intersections instead of the list comp: `{k: list(set(item)&unique_images) for k, items in d.iteritems()}`

Answer (score 5):

Just use sets:

```
d = {'cat':[1,2,3], 'dog':[2,3,4]}
common = set(d['cat']) & set(d['dog'])
out = [list(set(d['cat']) - common), list(set(d['dog']) - common)]
```

Extending this to more than two keys:

```
common = set.intersection(*(set(v) for k,v in d.items()))
out = [list(set(v) - common) for k,v in d.items()]
```

Comment: This does not appear to work.  Try `d = {'cat':[1, 2, 3], 'dog':[2, 3, 4], 'chicken': [2, 4, 5, 6]}`

Comment: Side-note: `set.intersection` doesn't need the arguments to be sets; any iterable works, so preconverting is pointless. And since you're not using the keys for anything, `set.intersection(*(set(v) for k,v in d.items()))` could simplify to the faster and simpler `set.intersection(*d.values())`.

Comment: @alexander it wasn't clear whether the OP wanted to only remove images that were included by every class or were merely included in more than one class. I assumed the former.